# Matplotlib plotting undefined plot out of nowhere

Tags: python, matplotlib

First of all, I apologize if this is not the place to post these kind of questions.

The issue is that matplotlib is apparently plotting a graph (I can recognize it from an old plot, so it's not some completely random graph) whenever I execute a script. Let me explain further.

The file is a test file, `module_test.py` and I have been trying to recognize where this problem may come from. Now I have written

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

*literally* at the top of the script and when I run the test via `python -m package.tests.module_test`, that "random" graph pops up. It also pops up with any other test script, but doesn't show up when using python in the command console. The tests run fine otherwise.

Does anybody have any idea why this happens? I have tried deleting `__pycache__` from all folders related to the issue, but of no help.

Here is the picture. It's a plot from a lab report I did months ago.

[image: This is the graph]

Comment: Is there `matplotlib`-using code somewhere else in the `package` in question?

Comment: @DavisHerring wow, yes. And I found the module that's doing that - it had a plot that wasn't closed, and it was getting imported by the `__all__` inside the `__init__` from the subpackage containing it. I'm surprised such bizarre things could happen. But it's fixed now. Thank you. Should I delete the question or let someone answer in case someone else comes against this problem as well?

Comment: I think it’s a common enough problem (because `pyplot` is so broken).

Comment: @DavisHerring Ok, I'll leave it up then. I couldn't find any solutions on the net after 1 hour of exhaustive searching. If nobody answers I'll post an answer myself tomorrow to close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By way of its emulation of the MATLAB GUI, `matplotlib` (especially but not only `pyplot`) is **stateful**.  This is a polite way of saying that it has *global variables* and all the debugging pain that goes with them.

In particular, every plot created is **retained indefinitely** so that it can be referenced by its “figure number”.  It can also be the “current figure” for `pyplot`.

Importing a module from a package **implicitly imports** the containing package(s) first.  This is one of the reasons that merely importing a module should not have any **side effects** (but merely define classes, functions, and constants).  The combination of invisible side effects and action at a distance produces hilarity like that observed here.